# MongoDB - JSON "owner":{"$id":"511e152bd482f6bd1e000000"}

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb, cordova, jsonp

I am creating an iPhone app which I needed to convert to JSON from PHP array

Now I am wondering once I have it in JSON formate how do i tell the javascript to get owner ID

```
"owner":{"$id":"511e152bd482f6bd1e000000"}

xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("POST","http://service.ipetfindr.com/iOS/?uri=fetchpet/" + n[1],false);
    xmlhttp.send();

    var petJSON = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
navigator.notification.alert(petJSON[0].owner);
```

Thanks

EDIT

I ended up getting it to work by

```
petJSON[0].owner.$id
```

Comment: No i had to use petJSON[0].owner.$id

Comment: So basically, your question was how to access a property in a JavaScript object? What does it have to do with mongodb or jsonp or phonegap? Don't you think you made it a little too localized if the question itself was accessing a javascript object's property?

Comment: no i dont and it has everything to do with Mongodb as that is the database returning the json - the reason i asked is because i have always been use to getting the $id by _id which in this case did not work.